# JApplet loading screen while drawing

Tags: java, swing, loading, graphviz, japplet

How can I put a loading screen that would be visible in java applet until the graph is drawn?
My code:

```
public class Test extends JApplet 
{
    GrappaPanel gp = null;
    JPanel jpanel = null;
    JEditorPane dataDisplayer = null;
    Graph graph = null;
    JProgressBar progressBar = null;

    public void init() {      
        Parser program =null;
        InputStream input;
            String sgraph = getGraph();
            try {
                input = new ByteArrayInputStream(sgraph.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                program = new Parser(input);
                program.parse();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            graph = program.getGraph(); 
            gp = new GrappaPanel(graph);
            JScrollPane jspg = new JScrollPane(gp,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            GridBagLayout gb = new GridBagLayout();
            jpanel = new JPanel(gb);
            setContentPane(jpanel);
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.weighty = 1.0;
            gb.setConstraints(jspg,gbc);
            jpanel.add(jspg);   
    }

    private String getGraph(){
    ...
    }

}
```

Drawing the graph in the applet takes the biggest part of the loading time. Getting the string that represents graph and parsing it to Graph object is relatively cheap. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Anything taking a long time to complete should be done in a background thread such as is available with a SwingWorker object.

Comment: By the way, where do you "draw the graph"? What lines of code above take a long time to process? Also, it smells funny to me that you're parsing a String into some sort of graphic. Is this an XML String?

Comment: No, it's dot language which is used to describe a graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CardLayout` with the  `JProgressBar` (or an animated 'loading' icon) in one card, and the graph in the other.  Default to the 'loading' card first, then do the long running task in a `SwingWorker`.  When the results are returned, prepare the graph, add it to the other card & flip to that card.